# Having both a WiFi client and an Access Point on Pi Zero

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

I have read this thread:[rpi-zero-w-as-both-wifi-client-and-access-point](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/rpi-zero-w-as-both-wifi-client-and-access-point)

And I have followed the instructions in this post:[raspberry-pi-3-wifi-station-ap](http://imti.co/post/145442415333/raspberry-pi-3-wifi-station-ap)

Initially, I was getting errors on the AP but I read in another post I read that I needed to set the hostapd path in the /etc/init.d/hostapd in addition to setting it in /etc/default. When I did that the errors went away. This step was not in the posts mentioned above.

Have the issues to get this working on the Pi Zero W been resolved? I have followed the instructions explicitly (with my addition above) and everything looks good.

The problem that I am having is that the SSID is not being broadcast.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would love to respond to the other post you mentioned ([RPI zero W as both Wifi client and access point](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/rpi-zero-w-as-both-wifi-client-and-access-point)), but it currently requires 10 reputation, and I don't have it. Nonetheless, I also read that post and failed to get everything working, but eventually determined a solution that works.

I wrote a blog post about it here: https://blog.thewalr.us/2017/09/26/raspberry-pi-zero-w-simultaneous-ap-and-managed-mode-wifi/

Hope that helps, as it's working great for me!

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks so much for the thorough post.

Comment: No problem! I've actually been meaning to go back and modify it a bit based on suggestions from people in the comments and on Reddit, but I haven't gotten around to it. Please do read those as well, as there are some tips that make the whole thing a bit cleaner.